# STM32 STEVAL-Spin3202 Motor control - Issues with driving power MOSFETs with PWM

Tags: stm32, pwm, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller, hal

I've been struggling with my new STEVAL-Spin3202 board from STM. It is using the STSpin32F0a motor driver with STM32F031C6 MCU. The ultimate goal is to control a BLDC motor with six-step sensor-less control.

I am trying to turn on one of the MOSFETs of the inverter in order to measure some voltage on one of the 3 phases. I'm trying to generate a PWM signal using the advanced timer TIM1 dedicated for this purpose. No matter how I try, I always measure the same voltage on all 3 phases.

I'm using a 20V power source, I've tried some code that played with some LEDs on the board, so the board's power should be fine. The source of the MOSFETs in the upper stage of the inverter is on 20V, as expected. But I cannot get the transistors to open.

I am using the CubeMX software (6.8.1) provided by STM to generate the HAL code.
All guides I've seen around the web use the same code as I do. To turn the MOSFET on, I'm using 20KHz PWM with around 80% duty-cycle, so the voltage measured should be around 16V. But for some unknown reason, I always measure the same voltage on all three phases regardless on the state the of the MCU output. Some code snippets:

This is the main function, here I just call init functions and try to start PWM and turn on the lower-stage MOSFET.

```
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_TIM1_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
    
    htim1.Instance->ARR = 2400-1;
    htim1.Instance->CCR1 = 2000;
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_13, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_15, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_14, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_1);

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}
```

And here is the initialization function for TIM1:

```
static void MX_TIM1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM1_Init 0 */

  TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig = {0};
  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};
  TIM_OC_InitTypeDef sConfigOC = {0};
  TIM_BreakDeadTimeConfigTypeDef sBreakDeadTimeConfig = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM1_Init 1 */
  htim1.Instance = TIM1;
  htim1.Init.Prescaler = 0;
  htim1.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim1.Init.Period = 2400-1;
  htim1.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim1.Init.RepetitionCounter = 0;
  htim1.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
  if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim1, &sClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_Init(&htim1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim1, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sConfigOC.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_PWM1;
  sConfigOC.Pulse = 2000;
  sConfigOC.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sConfigOC.OCNPolarity = TIM_OCNPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sConfigOC.OCFastMode = TIM_OCFAST_DISABLE;
  sConfigOC.OCIdleState = TIM_OCIDLESTATE_RESET;
  sConfigOC.OCNIdleState = TIM_OCNIDLESTATE_RESET;
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim1, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.OffStateRunMode = TIM_OSSR_DISABLE;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.OffStateIDLEMode = TIM_OSSI_DISABLE;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.LockLevel = TIM_LOCKLEVEL_OFF;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.DeadTime = 0;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.BreakState = TIM_BREAK_DISABLE;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.BreakPolarity = TIM_BREAKPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.AutomaticOutput = TIM_AUTOMATICOUTPUT_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_ConfigBreakDeadTime(&htim1, &sBreakDeadTimeConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM1_Init 2 */
  HAL_TIM_MspPostInit(&htim1);

}
```

I've also tried turning on the upper-stage MOSFET with GPIO (so it would 'open all the way'), but with no success.
Considering that otherwise the board is functioning as proper, and knowing that I'm (hopefully) starting the PWM the right way, I'm starting to consider hardware fault.

Can someone please check whether I'm missing/forgetting anything?

Comment: Are you using "open" in the context of an open switch or open circuit, where no current flows, or in the context of an open gate on a path, which allows passage (some current flows)? It would help to use terminology like 'on' and 'off' instead to avoid that kind of ambiguity.

Comment: I mean "open" as in open gate, but I will fix it, thank you